# titanium appcelerator Window pixel format

Tags: titanium

Hi am developing an android app , how can i set the window pixel format to ARGB_888, please help me

var loginWindowMain = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        url:'./view/Login.js',
       backgroundImage:"./images/mainwindow_bg.png",
    exitOnClose:true,
    });

Answer (score 0):

This [Android: Expose Window Pixel Format](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4104) should help you.

Comment: i can't find out thiswindowPixelFormat: Ti.UI.Android.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565